# How to prevent type erasure?

Tags: java, generics, compilation, refactoring, type-erasure

I have a method that i want to refactor, and it looks (well, very much simplified) like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair;

private int foo(Pair<String, ?>... params) {
    if (params[0].snd instanceof String) {
        // do something
        return 0;
    } else if (params[0].snd instanceof ArrayList) {
        // do something else
        return 1;
    }
    return -1; // realistically in the code base, this line will never happen **edit: disregard this line
}
```

so i was thinking i'd do something like split it up into two methods so that i don't have to do type checking. (is this even a good refactor?)

so i wanted to do something like this:

```
private int foo(Pair<String, String>... params) {
    // do something
    return 0;
}

private int foo(Pair<String, ArrayList>... params) {
    // do something else
    return 1;
}
```

But the compiler keeps telling me that both `foo()` methods have the same type erasure. Is java just erasing everything that `Pair<A, B>` knows? If so, what's the best way to refactor then? (or does it need refactoring)

Comment: I would use your first method. However I would replace `return -1;` with `throw new IllegalArgumentsException("message");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At compile time Java will [erase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the type information of Generics. There is no way to prevent that. At runtime, Pair doesn't have `<A,B>` it is effectively `<Object,Object>`.

As for refactoring it, there are a few things you might prefer (but apart from one recommendation) there's not much that could be improved in your example - I'd probably use a single else (if that last line can't happen. And I'd use a List instead of a specific type of List.

```
private int foo(Pair<String, ?>... params) {
  if (params[0].snd instanceof String) {
    return 0;
  } else { //if(params[0].snd instanceof List) { //is a List interface, not which List
    // do something else
    return 1;
  }
// return -1; // If it can't happen, why have it here.
}
```

Comment: Well, there are no `Pair<Object, Object>` either. There are just `Pair` after erasure.

Comment: @RohitJain True. Added effectively to clarify.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you have any suggestions to go about refactoring the method that i posted?

Comment: @DavidT. I added two (small) suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that

```
private int foo(Pair<String, String>... params) {
    return 0;
}

private int foo(Pair<String, ArrayList>... params) {
    return 1;
}
```

if this code were allowed, it wouldn't have much use. You know what type you're passing into foo. It's whatever the type of the reference is, not the type of the actual object. So just replace all calls to this where you'd pass a `Pair<String, String>` with just `0`.

That is, which method is called should be determinable at compile time. Not at runtime. And if it's determinable at compile time, you don't need to call the method at all.

Comment: oh sorry, i hid a lot of details from the code to make it say `return 0`.

Comment: @DavidT. ah, okay. To me it looked like the purpose of the method was determining if something was a `Pair<String, String>` or `Pair<String, ArrayList>`

Comment: no worries, what you said made sense given my mistake. +1 upvote.

Comment: @DavidT. java actually seems to double end you here. The method that is called is determined at compile time. For example, if you have a foo(Pair<A, B>), and try to pass in a Pair<C, D> into it, java will complain even though it's technically Pair<Object, Object> on both ends. However it won't let you create a method Pair<C, D>. It seems to me that this should be a perfectly implementable feature. Oh well.